# How to properly import npm packages in react

Tags: javascript, jquery, import, npm, requirejs

So I'm using a few plugins that I've used before and have worked in projects without react. The plugins I'm using are:

-Bootstrap

-Bootstrap-select

-DataTables

I'm trying to use the by using the `import` feature, however they don't work if I don't include them in my `index.html` (via CDN).

The problem I get with DataTables is that I get a `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined(…)` error. I've tried some recommended fixes which are:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
window.jQuery = $;
```

and

```
global.jQuery = require('jquery');
```

But neither solves the problem until I put in the CDN.

My other problem is bootstrap-select not working as intended. I use the `.selectpicker()` function and it creates the necessary 'look'. But when I click the select, nothing happens, no dropdown occurs. I've even imported the dropdown that's required but I'm not sure if it's correct.

```
import "bootstrap/js/dropdown";
```

So my overall question is, how should I import the packages to make them work (optimally without needing the CDNs) and what is wrong with bootstrap-select.

What my imports look like right now:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
window.jQuery = $;
global.jQuery = require('jquery');
import "bootstrap";
import DataTable from 'bootstrap';
global.DataTable = DataTable;
import "datatables.net";
import "datatables.net-buttons";
import "datatables.net-select";
import "bootstrap/js/dropdown";
import "bootstrap-select";
```